# Synonymize [web-browser] and [browsers] with [browser]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[web-browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) is only used once and [browsers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browsers) four times.

Sure, I could edit the posts but I think that making these two synonyms of [browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) is the better approach. Sooner or later someone else will use them again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest synonymizing [web-browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) to [browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser), but removing [browsers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browsers) from all questions that currently have it..

As long as [browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) exists, and has a decent wiki extract popping up for it (which it does), I don't see why anyone would ever use the longer [browsers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browsers) when the shorter version would have already been suggested by the auto-complete.

The only reason I could ever see to separate the tags is if we wanted the singular to be the Android default Browser app, and the plural to be for web browsers in general. As this isn't the case, [browsers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browsers) should die.